How to Use the Point Erase Mode with the Ctrl Shortcut in Grease Pencil Brush?
In Grease Pencil, I often manually switch from the Brush to the Eraser tool when I want to erase stroke portions, preferring the Point mode.

I recently discovered a shortcut that allows me to hold Ctrl while using the Brush tool to temporarily invert it into an Eraser. However, this shortcut defaults to the Dissolve erase mode. Is there a way to make the Ctrl shortcut use the Point erase mode instead of manually switching to the Eraser tool?
In the Edit > Preferences I cannot find anything to change the default behavior from Dissolve to Point:


I was looking for exactly the same thing and accidentally stumbled upon it: in the Properties window go to Tool, go to the Eraser section and select Eraser Point as the Default Eraser Brush. I hope this helps!


nice thank you very much! First you have to switch to the eraser tool and set it to Point. and then you can do this setting it works :)
